# How to use ServerSideRendering and state management like UseState,UseEffects in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, state-management, framer-motion

**Hello I want to know how to use State Management(UseState, UseEffects) in Next JS using server-side rendering without using 'use client' at the top.**

**And Will it decrease my page's performance using State Management(UseState, UseEffects) in client side?**

**Can I use Framer-Motion in Next JS ?**

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import {Box,Button,Input } from '@mui/material';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import {motion , useScroll, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import Image from 'next/image';


function page({ initialData }) {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(initialData);

  return (
    <h1>Hello {data} </h1>
  )
}

export default page;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an example of useEffect and useState with NextJS.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function page({ initialData }) { 
   const [data, setData] = useState(initialData)

   useEffect(() => setData('Name'), [data])

   return <h1>Hello {data}</h1>
}
    
export default page;
```

Comment: Thank you Robin how can i use for server side ? Can you help me how to pass function as props from client side to server side

Answer (score 1):

No , using `useEffect` and `useState` doesnot lower the performence if used correctly. You can use UseEffect like this to run it on coponent mounting (starting)

```
useEffect(()=>{
setState() // set the state here to or do any other work
},[])
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad how can i use for server side ? Can you help me how to pass function as props from client side to server side

Answer (score 1):

The answers prior seem to address pre V13.

I am noob at next.j and react so please correct me and I will re-write my answer. But I write this answer because this topic is not well understood by us noob's and hence we need help.

I have been struggling in the same paradigm, and nobody answers this question because V13 is relatively new, or in my case they answer it in Typescript or in vue, or angular and I do not understand it.

**From my understanding the basic answer is "You Cannot"**
Making the process/structure very difficult.
(Framer-Motion I have no idea)

You want to have most of your app running Server-side, but you also want to useState

**So the way I have structured it, each component that uses state/useState (counter to all previous guidance), gets its own, and those that don't use state don't.
for example your home page which should have no state requirements can render server-side, but your filtered products which need state will be client side.
The problem this creates is the approach of putting state at the parent level cause this client-side situation.**

In other words you want Auth state in the header, but the main container running server-side

hence header needs its own state management, or even better the login/logout buttons need their own state, however this now create another issue, whereby your header does not re-render due to the soft page reload, and hence now you need a Routing solution for when top level states (like Auth) change.

An alternative is to reload every page so that the data comes from server without state, this then defeats the speed of react and is less performant.

I will update this with a link to my new question here that goes down this avenue.