# How to manage header state without useState & 'use client' at the top level

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

The below may work but, **Is it the correct way to do things in next.js 13?**
**Is using a login page as a routing page with hard reloads the right way to go about it?**
please also note that there is not a lot of information about this 'use client' complexity; to the point that a lot of tutorials about next.js 13 do not even show the 'use client' annotation and hence do not work.

**Here is my tech stack**
Next.js, AWS Amplify, AWS Cognito, Javascript, App Router (next.js v13), and tailwind.

**App Structure**

```
src/app/
--->layout.js (header.jsx, children, footer.jsx)
--->page.js (Home Content)
--->guest/
--->--->page.js (guest Content)
--->(Auth)/freemium/
--->--->--->page.js (freemium authenticated Content)
--->(Auth)/premium/
--->--->--->page.js (premium authenticated Content)
--->(Auth)/login/
--->--->--->page.js (login and redirect)
```

**This linked question has the route cause and reason for my question:
[How to use ServerSideRendering and state management like UseState,UseEffects in Next JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76926716/7012749)**

**Here are the constraints/issues:**

- I have run into (Perceived constraints based on my noob knowledge):
  Cannot manage header state (loggedIn) at top of app or in layout.js
  because the **useState** requires the  **'use client'** annotation,
  making the whole app client side. please correct me at any stage.
- Initially I created nav links direct to my child pages wrapped in
  **withAuthenticator**, but they do not update my header state(loggedIn) which updates my login/logout button. it does not
  update because of the soft loading of my routes.
- withAuthenticator I do not see how I can manage the Login Flow, for example at the end of Auth routing to a different page. (hence the login page doing this (wrapped in withAuthenticator) all pages are wrapped anyway for security purposes.

**Here is part of my layout.js**

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={font.className}>
        <div className="my-Wrapper">
          <Header/>
          {children}
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**I have routed all header.jsx Auth links through the login page** using a redirect to the required page, if the user is not authenticated, otherwise go direct to each page

```
//header.jsx inside my layout.js (layout is not using 'use client')
'use client'
import { Amplify, Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Dialog, Popover } from '@headlessui/react';
import Link from "next/link";
import awsExports from '@/aws-exports';
Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });
const menuItems = [{ id: 1, name: 'guest', description: 'check us out', mURL: '/guest'}];

const Header = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser()
    async function checkUser() {
      try {
        const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        setUser(user);
        setUiState('signedIn');
        menuItems.push(
          { id:2, name:'freemium', description:'use for free', mURL:'/freemium'},
          { id:3, name:'premium', description:'pay us money', mURL:'/premium'}
        )
      } catch(err) {
        setUser(null);
        setUiState('signedOut');
        menuItems.push(
          { id:2, name:'freemium', description:'use for free', mURL:'/login?redirect=/freemium'},
          { id:3, name:'premium', description:'pay us money', mURL:'login?redirect=/premium'}
        )
      }
    }
    console.log(menuItems);
  }, [])
...
//below only shows the Log In and Sign Out button based on the Auth state
  return (
//some code goes here to render the NAV
    <div>
      {
        uiState === 'signedOut' && (
          <Link data-name="loginlink"   href="/login?redirect=${theRedirect}" 
            className="my-BlueButton"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Log in
          </Link>
        )
      }
      {
        uiState === 'signedIn' && (
          <button className="my-DarkRedButton" onClick={() => {
            signOut()
            setUser(null)
            setUiState('signedOut')
          }}>
            Sign out <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
          </button>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
```

**If not logged in the User is soft directed to the login page...**

**But this login page does a hard redirect causing a full page reload, allowing the Header to pick up state again** (this code I am also unsure about I should possibly be using the router???)

```
// /app/(Auth)/login/page.js
'use client'
import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import awsExports from '@/aws-exports';

Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });

function Login({searchParams}) {
  const redirectPage = searchParams.redirect;
  window.location.href = redirectPage;
}

export default withAuthenticator(Login)
```

The above is the only way I could see managing the header's state of Auth.
An alternative option (I do not understand yet) would be to use hub.listen ; but I do not know how to implement this.

***Please advise if the above is the correct way to structure next.js 13, to maintain as much server-side rendering as possible?***